# Taking in Array as path param and hibernate query

Tags: sql, hibernate, list

I am trying to retrieve a list of students from a list inserted into the pathparam which retrieve the students based on their studentId using hibernate.

To retrieve a single student with a single studentId, I use the following code which is working.

```
 student = (student) session.createQuery("from student as student
 where student.studentId = :studentId")
.setString( "studentId", studentId ).uniqueResult();
```

However, when I try to pass in a list of studentIDs to return more than 1 student, I tried this code but it doesn't work. Hopefully someone can shed some light.
Any help is appreciated.

```
students = session.createQuery("from student as student 
where student.studentId in :studentList").setParameterList( "studentList", studentList ).list();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably is due to missing parenthesis around `:studentList`; correct syntax for `IN` clause is `IN (values list)` so change your query as

```
students = session.createQuery("from student as student 
where student.studentId in (:studentList)").setParameterList( "studentList", studentList ).list();
```

From Query.setParametersList() javadoc:

> Bind multiple values to a named query parameter. The Hibernate type of
>   the parameter is first detected via the usage/position in the query
>   and if not sufficient secondly guessed from the class of the first
>   object in the collection. This is useful for binding a list of values
>   to an expression such as **foo.bar in (:value_list)**.

Comment: That seem to give me this error
java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Integer
any idea?

Comment: Is studentList of same type of studentId? Check my answer about type detection

Comment: that seem to return some light, is there any way to test it in my url? XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX/StudentWS/getStudentsFromStudentList/{1,3,5} or is it 1%3%5

Comment: `Integer[] studentList = new Integer[]{1,3,5}` or 
`List<Integer> studentList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
studentList.add(1);studentList.add(3);studentList.add(5);`
You can't use a String with separated values as parameter! You have to transform it! But this is unrelated to your answer, just look at `String.split()`.

Comment: @LucaBassoRicci Im having the same problems for days, i could not figure it out, could you please try to help me https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46154813/setparameterlist-does-not-return-full-result-set