# setParameterList() does not return full result set

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot

I want to make my small spring  project effectively. So I use `IN` clause instead of using loops in hql.

**01) Question in `setParameterList()`**

> To use `setParameterList()`, we have to pass list object

```
List<Department> listDeptmntId = reportService.listDepartmentID(companyId); //list of objects

String hql = "select s.department.departmentName, g.dateTime from Gauge g inner join g.survey s where s.department in (:dpts)";
Query query = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createQuery(hql);
query.setParameterList("dpts",listDeptmntId);
```

The query works fine. But this return only **one (first object in `listDeptmntId` list)** resultset, does not return other results.

I tries to pass integer list like *[1,2,3]* using following method also not working.

```
List<Integer> dptIds=listDeptmntId.stream().map((Department::getDepartmentId()).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

**02) Question in `setParameter()`**

```
int cId=10;
String hql="...... companyId=:id" 
Query query = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createQuery(hql);
query.setParameter("id",cId);
```

Sometime when I use parameter passing ("**=:**") , it does not work for ***Integers*** .  But directly setting variable to query like following is working

```
int cId=10;
String hql="...... companyId="+cId
Query query = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createQuery(hql);
```

My code may be wrong because I'm going through ebooks and referring materials to do the project. Thank you in advance.

Comment: what did you mean *Sometime when I use parameter passing ("=:") , it does not work for Integers* ?

Comment: because it does not work, i could not figure out what happens

Comment: This question needs:
1. to be splitted in 2 different questions
2. integrate code with a working example (do you use Query.list() or uniqueResult() or enything else?), better with Hibernate config

Comment: Some advice:
1. enable debug and check for  generated SQL: is generated SQL correct?
2. Q1: are you sure the inner join is satisfied for all records in Gauge table?
3. Dig a bit deeper in Hibernate code with your debug

Answer (score 1):

I generally do `IN(?, ..., ?)` using an `java.sql.Array`.

```
long[] deptIds = listDeptmntId.toArray(new long[listDeptmntId.size()];
java.sql.Array array = conn.createArrayOf("LONG", deptIds);
query.setPameter("depts", array);
```

Comment: HQL queries uses (mapped) objects not java.sql package library (https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.2/api/org/hibernate/Query.html#setParameterList(java.lang.String, java.util.Collection))

Answer (score 0):

q1) Check the join (can't see any other reasons to return just one object). And passing [1,2,3] won't work with that query because in query you're dealing with department object. If you want [1,2,3] to work change the query to check for dept-ids like this -> "select s.department.departmentName, g.dateTime from Gauge g inner join g.survey s where s.department.id in (:id-list)"

q2) You've already created the query object when you set the parameter, so setting parameter at that point might not affect the query object. (Your "+" approach works since the parameter is set to the query when creating the query object.)

Comment: for the first question, when i give manually its working. Eg : 
`...where s.department in (1) // return resultset for 1`
`...where s.department in (2) // return resultset for 2`

But `...where s.department in (1,2) // return resultset for 1 only`